# Can someone explain the use of * in this Python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        name, *line = input().split()
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        student_marks[name] = scores
    query_name = input()
```

Can someone explain the use of `*` in the above Python snippet?

Comment: For further reading - [unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's called **unpacking**. It puts the first item in `name` and all other items in a list called `line`.

```py
name, *line = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(name) #1
print(line) #[2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the `name` variable holds first element that input.().split()
returns, by using `*line` everything after first element is holded by `line` variable.